# PostgreSQL Syntax error I do not understand

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I have the next SQL cmd that postgress says it is not correct:

```
SQL State  : 42601
Error Code : 0
Message    : ERROR: syntax error at or near "NOT"
  Position: 41
Location   : db/migration/postgresql/V2.5.0.20180730192730__schema-add-kerberos-to-source.sql (/opt/tomcat/webapps/WebAPI/WEB-INF/classes/db/migration/postgresql/V2.5.0.20180730192730__schema-add-kerberos-to-source.sql)
Line       : 1
Statement  : ALTER TABLE webapi.source ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS krb_auth_method VARCHAR DEFAULT 'PASSWORD' NOT NULL
```

Any ideas why this is wrong? I am using psql 9.5.9

Comment: To be clear, the version of **psql** (the default command-line interface) does not have to be the same as the version of the Postgres server you are connecting to. `SELECT version();` returns the version of the server you are currently connected to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ALTER TABLE ... ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS` was added with Postgres 9.6. You can find it in [the *current* manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html).

You may want to upgrade to a current version anyway. Version 9.5 is getting old, version 12 will be out soon.

If you stick with 9.5, at least consider what [the Postgres project advises](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/):

> We always recommend that all users run the latest available minor release for whatever major version is in use.

The current minor release is 9.5.19 at the time of writing. You are missing out on several years of security updates and bug fixes.

Answer (score 0):

The [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/sql-altertable.html) says, there is no such thing as `ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS`, only `ADD COLUMN`.

Comment: Edit - I missed the version note.  You are correct.

----

It exists in 9.6 - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/sql-altertable.html